# What's the slickest way to show $[x,v,x\times v]\in SO(3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, determinant, orthonormal

Given $x,v$ are orthonormal in $\Bbb R^3$ i.e. $\|x\|=\|v\|=1,\,\langle x,v\rangle = 0$, what's the slickest way to show that $[x,v,x\times v]\in SO(3)$? In particular, how to show that $\det [x,v,x\times v] = 1$ instead of $-1$?

This is of course intuitively obvious and easy to wrap one's mind around, but I just couldn't find a rigorous proof. For example, it is tempting to say "well we can always find some rotation $R$ which sends $[e_1,e_2,e_3]$ to $[x,v,x\times v]$" but this ends up circular reasoning because a rotation is exactly an element in $SO(3)$.

Another possible approach I think is to show the tangent bundle $TS^2$ is a *connected* topological space. Once we show it, we can proceed to show $T_1S^2$, the unit tangent bundle, being obviously a continuous image of $TS^2$ by a normalisation map must be connected too, and again its image under the determinant map $\det$ must also be connected and hence can only be the singleton $\{1\}$. But how to show $TS^2$ is connected in the first place which might be much harder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using the formula $$\det[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}]=(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})\cdot\mathbf{c}$$ which is a direct consequence of expanding the determinant along the third column.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how do you define the cross product.

Using the coordinatewise definition, Rene provided you with a strong hint.

If, though, we define the cross product through the Hodge star

$$a \times b = \star (a \wedge b),$$

the determinant of three 3-dimentional vectors as

$$\det(a,b,c) = \star(a \wedge b \wedge c),$$

and use the identity

$$a \wedge (\star b) = \langle a, b \rangle \omega,$$

where $\omega \in \Lambda^3 \mathbb{R}^3$ is the preffered volume element (usually $e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3$ in terms of a basis), and the definition of scalar product of $k$-vectors, then the answer is a straightforward alrebraic manipulation:

$$\det(x,v,x \times v)=\star(x \wedge v \wedge (x \times v)) = \star(x \wedge v \wedge \star(x \wedge v)) = \star(\|x \wedge v\|^2 \omega) = \|x \wedge v\|^2 = \\ = \begin{vmatrix}\langle x,x \rangle & \langle x,v \rangle \\ \langle v,x \rangle & \langle v,v \rangle \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = 1$$

Comment: The answer by Rene Schipperus is not coordinate based; that formula defines (or can be used to define) the cross product in an abstract oriented three dimensional real inner product space (where oriented means one of the two volume forms compatible with the inner product has been selected; it is the $\det$ in the formula).